# Deploying a Docker hub private image on a swarm (using a CI server)

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, dockerhub

I am trying to work out how to use a private repository on docker hub in a swarm. I can not find any instructions anywhere.

I have a linux user called "codefreshrunner", the CI server does an ssh login to a server on the swarm and runs a command like:

docker service create --with-registry-auth --name my_docker_hub_0_1_2 --network main_net metcarob/my_docker_hub_image:0.1.2

When the docker registry is not private this works without a problem.
When I set the registry to be private I get the following:

"No such image: metcarob/saas_…"

I have tried manually logging in to the server as codefreshrunner and preforming the docker login command. I have checked the ~/.docker/config.json file is created and is running.

Can anyone point me at any documentation on how to do this? All the documentation I have found is how to use a private registry with a swarm, but I don't want to use a private registry, just a private repository in the public docker hub.

Comment: Try prefixing your `registry:port` before the image. `myregistry:5000/metcarob/my_docker_hub_image:0.1.2`

Comment: But I don't have a registry, I am using docker hub

Comment: Ok. Is it working when you do `docker login` manually?

Comment: It is working when I ssh to the server and run docker login manually, but I am using the codefresh rdocker step which lets me run exactly one command on the swarm machine and for me that command is the docker service create command

Comment: no, `docker login` is an one time step. You can `ssh` and do a `docker login` once and then try your service script.

Comment: By one time I assume you mean one time per login session. As the rdocker script provided by codefresh runs on their server and handles the SSH connection itself I can't add a docker login step to the command. My only option would then be to build my own rdocker. I was hoping the docker login command would be needed just once then I could use the rdocker script as is

Comment: I did a quick google. Looks like codefresh provides option for using private docker hub - https://codefresh.io/docs/docs/docker-registries/external-docker-registries/docker-hub/

Comment: I looked at that. One option is for me to switch to using that repository instead of the docker hub one but presumably I would have to log into that one as well.

Comment: Yes, you have to login. I don't have much idea about codefresh.

Comment: I think I can send multiple commands through rdocker by joining them with \&\&

Answer (score 0):

Try a `docker login` within the script you start service from.

Comment: I am using the rdocker script provided by codefresh so this may not be possible. I was trying to avoid having to write my own script but it sounds like I can no longer avoid that :(

Comment: Do you have a link to the script you used?

Comment: The script is documented by codefresh here: https://codefresh.io/docs/docs/deploy-your-containers/docker-swarm/ Thanks to your prompt they actually have an example which uses the docker login command there, I think they have updated the docs and that now answers my question.